Heroku - devDependencies not being installed on build phase
I'm trying to deploy my first app to Heroku
Per the documentation, Heroku build phase should install the devDependencies, right?
But it always fail with tsc not found
I even tried to add typescript as a dependency, not devDependency, the tsc worked during the build phase, but the frontend failed due to the @types/react not installed
It should work and I'm not sure why it's not working
I have this structure currently:
- backend
-- package.json
-- src
- frontend
-- package.json
-- src
- build (this is in .gitignore and contains both backend and frontend builds)
- package.json
- Procfile

In my root package.json, I have:
{
...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "start": "cd build/backend/src && node index.js",
    "build": "cd frontend && yarn install && cd ../backend && yarn install"
  },
...
}

my Procfile: web: yarn start
backend package.json:
{
...
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "yarn run build",
    "build": "tsc --build --verbose && tsc-alias",
    "postbuild": "cp package.json ../build/backend/package.json && cp .env ../build/backend || : && cd ../build/backend && yarn install --prod",
    "start": "ts-node-dev -r tsconfig-paths/register --project ./tsconfig.json ./src/index.ts --diagnostics --ignore-watch node_modules",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "tsc-alias": "^1.8.10",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
    ...
  }
...
}

and my frontend package.json:
{
...
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "yarn run build",
    "start": "vite",
    "build": "tsc --build --verbose && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
    ...
  }
...
}

[EDIT]
Got it working by with this workaround on my root package.json, I'm not sure if this is the best option
{
...
    "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "start": "cd build/backend/src && node index.js",
    "postinstall": "cd frontend && yarn install --production=false && cd ../backend && yarn install --production=false",
    "build": "cd frontend && yarn build && cd ../backend && yarn build"
  },
...
}

